# Configure wxwidgets with Codeblocks

Tags: c++, user-interface, cmake, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I want to build C++ GUI programs using Codeblocks+Wxwidgets+cmake. I tried to configure Wxwidgets with codeblocks IDE following the instructions given in the [wxWidgets Discussion Forum](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=47061#:%7E:text=Code%20Blocks%20Installation&text=Run%20Code%3A%3ABlocks%20and,shows%20the%20location%20I%20chose.) as well as other Youtube tutorials.

I followed the youtube tutorials below.

[Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHkb1XrtseY)

But, when 'DEBUG' and 'RELEASE' are being built, it keeps showing some kind of errors. As a result, the building was failed.

[image: Errors]

Please help me to solve this or suggest another easy way to do C++ GUI projects.

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not post the screenshots. Please copy and paste the errors as they appears in the build log. That will make the life of whoever will help you much easier. On top of that there are blind/legally blind people who also are very familiar with the programming, but they will not be able to help you since no screen reader can read screenshots. So please avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent document explaining how to set up C::B with wxWidgets. It can be found [here](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=47231).

It is not about CMake-thingy, but it is written with enough details to help people understand how to setup the IDE.

So I suggest to delete C::B, delete wxWidgets, delete all projects you setup before and start all over, following the instructions from PB to a T.

If you hit a wall or something will not work - please comeback with the exact explanation.